# How to eliminate the distortion in live streaming Nodejs + ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, distortion

I tried Live video Streaming with NodeJS and ffmpeg encoder. It works with a lag of around 2sec and with a distortion as well. Lag does not matter as there is always. But I need to eliminate the video distortion as much as possible. So what would be the suitable bit rates and is there a better encoder to do this? In ffmpeg, it encodes to mpegts so is there a more preferable format than mpegts ? plz help

my encoding code was

```
ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f dshow -i video="HP HD Webcam":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -f mpegts -v:b 800 -r 100 http://localhost:8082/abc/640/480/
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "distortion"?

Comment: The video is having green boxes and some pixels are not rendering. I mean the source stream is not coming out correctly.

Comment: Using two methods of rate control (`-qp 0` and presumably `-b:v 800`) are mutually exclusive, so one will be ignored. `-v:b` is not an option; perhaps you meant `-b:v`. Looks like you forgot a `k`: the `-b:v` option takes a value in bits, so you're tying to encode 800 bits per second, so `-b:v 800k` would make more sense if you want to use that option.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a video codec, so it used mpeg2 (the default for [mpegts](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/mpegtsenc_8c.html#ada9f596d2c8e91894e0730d665374d9f)). You want to use H264, so use -c:v libx264:

```
ffmpeg -s 640x480 -f dshow -i video="HP HD Webcam":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -f mpegts -v:b 800 -r 100 http://localhost:8082/abc/640/480/
```

And then it should be fine. In addition, the green boxes sound like bugs (overflows?), so perhaps file a [bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) about them on the ffmpeg bug tracker.

Comment: I replaced my code with yours and then in the front end it does not decodes the stream I guess that is because the js file I have only decodes mpeg. could you assist me for that as well? Thanks...

Comment: I don't know what a js file is?

Comment: I am trying to encode the video with ffmpeg and decode the stream using javascript in the browser so that I can send it through http.

Comment: Find a h264 js decoder :). Or use something that's not javascript, I mean, all browsers support h264 in the video tag, why not just use that?